# GD library is still missing after I installed it

Tags: php, xplane

So I am creating a website for my virtual airline for xplane-11, and I came across this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Required GD library is missing in /var/www/html/vam/captcha/simple-php-captcha.php:13 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/vam/index.php(15): simple_php_captcha() #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/vam/captcha/simple-php-captcha.php on line 13
```

I have libgd-dev installed on my ubuntu 20.04 and I also have all the extensions uncommented in my php.ini file in the etc/apache2/sites-available folder. I am really frustrated at this point and any help given will be thanked.

Answer (score 3):

From the command line what do you get if you run

`php -m | grep -i gd`

If it returns

`gd`

Then the module is included and running in your version of PHP.

Otherwise I would try the following

`apt-get install php-gd`

Then run the `php -m | grep -gd` command again after restarting apache

Comment: I have done everything you said and its still not working

Comment: What do the following commands output? `lsb_release -a` `apachectl -v` and a full `php -m`

Comment: I have fixed it! Thank you! It turns out that I installed the .so thing on the wrong place

Comment: Hi Aero, thank you for letting us know. Did you build the packages from source then?

Comment: You have to specify the version number e,g, php7.4-gd